# How to establish connection between OXID shop and ONGR?

Tags: elasticsearch, symfony, oxid, ongr

We(me and my team) are doing some research, how ONGR and OXID communicate with each other as it is required for our next project.
We have already setup Demo app of the ONGR bundles and it is working.

However, we don't know which bundle has to be used for establishing communication between ONGR and OXID?
We have found one **"OXIDConnectorBundle"** inside **ongr-archive on github**, however this bundle is deprecated as mention in github OXIDConnectorBundle repository.
We have already tried to install **"OXIDConnectorBundle" in Symfony 3 version**, however we are facing problem with the installation and installation is unsuccessful.
Please check this link for more details about **OXIDConnectorBundle**: https://github.com/ongr-archive/OXIDConnectorBundle

So, can you please guide us if there is any other stable bundle for establishing communication between ONGR & OXID?

Below are the helpful links for better understanding on ONGR:

**ONGR:** http://ongr.io/

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned bundles from archive organisation are legacy and only for those who used them. During development, we noticed that to have a module in the OXID and push data to the Elasticsearch is tough to maintain. That said we changed behaviour completely to another way around. In ONGR you can use [API bundle](https://github.com/ongr-io/ApiBundle) and easy setup REST API for data import. As of OXID you only need to have a module to make an HTTP request to push data by single document or batch.